# How to build and chat app (with Group Chat and Private Messaging )using node.js socket.io and express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How to build an chat app which it can private message and chat with group?

Comment: Have a look at the [Get started from Socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started) and come back, when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very simple. But the answer is more complicated. You have to user Socket.IO package for node.js and Socket.IO-client for the frontend library(React.js, React Native, Flutter).

How does socket works.

```
io.to(socket.id).emit("event", data);
```

whenever a user joined to the server, socket details will be generated including ID. This is the ID really helps to send a message to particular people.

first we need to store all the socket.ids in array,

```
var people={};

people[name] =  socket.id;
```

So, now we can get that socket.id with the receiver name whenever we are sending message:

for this we need to know the receivername. You need to emit receiver name to the server.

final thing is:

```
 socket.on('chat message', function(data){
io.to(people[data.receiver]).emit('chat message', data.msg);
});
```

This is how private Chat will work.